# Tizen Mac OSX Installation Failure (sdb)

Tags: tizen, tizen-sdb

The installation keeps failing in slightly different ways.  I've chmod'd the tmp file.  I delete the tizen-sdk folder before each attempt.  I'm linking to the correct image.  I've updated HAXM.

(Almost) every time it comes down to an sdb error.

install-log:

http://pastebin.com/WviCKwtx

Answer (score 0):

The install script cannot write to `.profile` file (see the last line):

```
Execute sdb install script
Execute script starts...
    Current working directory. => /Users/Admin/tizen-sdk/temp
execute command => [/Users/Admin/tizen-sdk/temp/install.sh]
[sdb] + SDB_AC_NAME=.sdb-completion.bash
[sdb] + SDB_SETTING_PATH=/Users/Admin/.sdb
[sdb] + SDB_AC_SRC_PATH=/Users/Admin/tizen-sdk/tools/.sdb-completion.bash
[sdb] + SDB_AC_DST_PATH=/Users/Admin/.sdb/.sdb-completion.bash
[sdb] + BASH_RC=/Users/Admin/.profile
[sdb] + ENABLE_SDB_COMPLETION='# Enable programmable sdb completion features.\nif [ -f ~/.sdb/.sdb-completion.bash ]; then\n source ~/.sdb/.sdb-completion.bash\nfi'
[sdb] + rm -rf /Users/Admin/.sdb
[sdb] + mkdir -p /Users/Admin/.sdb
[sdb] + mv -f /Users/Admin/tizen-sdk/tools/.sdb-completion.bash /Users/Admin/.sdb/.sdb-completion.bash
[sdb] + '[' -f /Users/Admin/.profile ']'
[sdb] ++ grep 'source ~/\.sdb/\.sdb-completion\.bash' /Users/Admin/.profile
[sdb] + '[' -z ']'
[sdb] + echo -e '#' Enable programmable sdb completion 'features.\nif' '[' -f '~/.sdb/.sdb-completion.bash' '];' 'then\n' source '~/.sdb/.sdb-completion.bash\nfi'
[sdb] /Users/Admin/tizen-sdk/temp/install.sh: line 16: /Users/Admin/.profile: Permission denied
```

Make it writable by the script and you should be set.
Hope this helps.